# how to rename filenames in C

Tags: c

I wrote this piece of code that lists all JPG files in the current directory,

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h> 
int main() {
    char *ptrToSubString;
    char fileName[100];
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    dir = opendir(".");
    if (dir != NULL) {
            while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
                   strcpy(fileName,ent->d_name);
                   ptrToSubString = strstr(fileName,".jpg");
                   if (ptrToSubString != NULL) {
                       printf("%s",ent->d_name);
                   } else {
                      continue;
                   }
            }
            closedir(dir);
    } else {
            perror("");
            return 5;
 }
return 0;
}
```

but I'd like to add the functionality to rename the files to a unique filename, or append a unique identifier to the filename.

For instance, If the program lists the following filenames:

- facebook.png
- instagram.png
- twitter.png

I'd like to have them renamed to

- facebook-a0b1c2.png
- instagram-d3e4f5.png
- twitter-a6b7c9.png

any idea on how to achieve this? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: well if you know how to rename a file, just use a the original filename + a timestamp.

Comment: The `rename()` function is standard C. Constructing the arguments to it is more complicated.

Comment: Note: most file systems allow filenames to be longer than 100 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the name:

```
*(ptrToSubString++) = 0x0;
```

Then recombine the name adding a random hex sequence (or maybe a counter?)

```
snprintf(newFilename, SIZE_OF_NEWFILENAME_BUFFER,
     "%s-%06x.%s", fileName, rndhex, ptrToSubString);
```

call `rename()` on the new files.

**UPDATE**

As noticed by Zack, rename will not fail if the new file exists, so after generating `newFilename`, either `stat` (*mind the race condition -- see Zack's other comment*) or `open(newFilename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600)` must be used to verify the new name isn't in use. If it is, generate a new random and repeat.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! `rename` will *silently replace* an already-existing file.  You need to use `open(newname, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600)` first if you want to make sure not to clobber an existing file (this creates a file with the new name, failing if it already exists; if it succeeds, then you close the file descriptor and replace the placeholder file using `rename`).

Comment: Boy is my face red. @Zack, you're too right. I had seen the problem with already existing filenames, and I solved it *wrong*. Edited my answer.

Comment: Don't be too embarrassed, it's a common mistake -- but you shouldn't recommend `stat`, that doesn't do anything to 'claim' the new name, so another process could create it in between the `stat` and the `rename`. (Not likely to be a huge problem for this use case, but slight variations have caused serious data-loss and/or privilege escalation bugs in the past.)

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a `rename` function found in `stdio.h`. You could use that like this:

```
/* rename example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int result;
    char oldname[] ="oldname.txt";
    char newname[] ="newname.txt";
    result= rename( oldname , newname );
    if ( result == 0 )
        puts ( "File successfully renamed" );
    else
        perror( "Error renaming file" );
    return 0;
}
```

Just adapt this to your needs. You can also read up more on it [here.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/rename/)